# Determine the transfer function of a movement equation

Tags: control-theory, transfer-function

The problem is the following. I have to control a spaceship (assuming no gravity, no mass, no friction / no external forces). In other words, the first equation in [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18900/determining-the-transfer-function-of-cruise-control-given-characteristic-equatio) leads to $0 = 0$. My goal is to reach a position for a given acceleration (i.e. throttle).

The movement equation (assuming a constant acceleration) is the following: $x(t) = 0.5 * a * t^2 + v_0 * t + x_0$ where $v_0$ is the initial velocity and $x_0$ the initial position ($x_0 = 0$). Finally, I get $a = (goal - t*V_0) / t^2$ where $goal= target - traveled_distance$

I put this equation in my system. There is a sensor to measure the velocity. Each time the velocity is measure, I can send a new acceleration command.

I got the following plots (the first one is the acceleration, the second one the velocity, and the last one the trajectory)

[image]

On the last plot, we can clearly identify the response of a second order system. I also observed that increasing $t$ reduces the overshoot (so I guess that $t$ is acting like a proportional gain).

My question is what would be the corresponding transfer function? I tried to identify it with a second order differential equation but did not get any convincing results.

Comment: I fail to understand the meaning of a system discussing acceleration with no mass.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring your acceleration control rule (which I would not do this way) your transferfunction looks like this:
$$H(s) = \frac{1}{s^2}$$
where the input is the acceleration, the output is the position. Since you measure the velocity, the transferfunction changes to
$$H(s) = \frac{1}{s}$$
As for your control goal, you assume the acceleration is constant, however the plot shows otherwise. Other than that, its based upon the logic that within some time interval $t$, assuming constant velocity, the error changes to something. Increasing this $t$ allows it to respond less aggressive, thus less overshoot. I on the other hand advice to simply close the loop and use a PD controller to control the system:
$$T(s) = \frac{\frac{P+Ds}{s^2}}{1+\frac{P+Ds}{s^2}} = \frac{P+Ds}{s^2+P+Ds}$$
Where the error equals $Goal - x \approx Goal -(x_{prev} + v \cdot Ts)$ where $v$ is the measured velocity, $Ts$ the sampling rate and $x_{prev}$ the sum of all earlier measured $v\cdot Ts$ and $x0$. Do note that using an discrete integration like this might result in large offsets due to integrating noise (introducing drift).

Answer (score 0):

How would look like the block diagram then? I can only think about that:

[image]

You formula suggests an unit gain return though.

Comment: Integrating velocity does not yield acceleration, its the other way around ;). The output of the controller is an acceleration (usually a force, but we omit masses here). This means that your top diagram looks the most accurate. Estimating the position this manner should require a delay to ensure xprev is also updated each time step. If this is implemented in simulink, you should set the simulation solver to a constant time step to make it work. If not, you'd better off replacing this part with a 1/s block.